# Cant figure how my phone is full

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have a Galaxy S5 Neo, about 2 years old. For about a year, i have been getting notifications that the phone is full and cannot install updates etc.

I have gone through the phone a few times, deleted whatsapp videos and images and other stuff i don't need, and still is showing me 1.9GB free out off 11GB (this is after the clean up). When it gets to about 1GB of free space - it locks up and refuses to install updates.
I currently have 500MB of whatsapp images. All my own camera images and videos as well as music are all on the SD card.

Attaching an image of my folder root that i see on the computer - as well as tech specs.

Any tips appreciated.

[image: Folder root]
[image: Tech Specs]

Comment: Factory resetting it after you back up the data you need is probably the best option.

Comment: Have you already tried to search for apps that use too much storage? Like Facebook, Instagram, Google, etc... Tap "Clear Data" and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: @Fusseldieb - yes, i gained a few hundred MB

Comment: Are you using an external SD Card or the internal SD Card ... Some devices actually emulate the internal SD Card using space from the DATA Partition ( data/media/some location with emulated card ) ... This means that the internal SD Card will display the free space of your DATA region and not necessarily the free space of the emulated SD Card ...

Comment: @Zillinium - sorry not sure i understand the distinction. The SD card is installed in the phone and is set to save images and music on it.